# Bot doesn't read the second reaction when user reacts to 2 reaction.. discord.py

Tags: list, if-statement, async-await, discord, discord.py

I have a code which the bot needed to read the both reactions of the user on a message but with this code, the bot doesn't print the "second check" which is meant by like bot not reading the second reaction and stopping after the first one come true

```py
reacttn = True
def check(reaction, user):
  return user == members.users[members.leader].user and reaction.message.id == ttreact.id
while reacttn == True:
  reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)

  if len(members.users) == 2:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
      print("first check")
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
      print("second check")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    reacttn = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence


def sequence(seq):
   if seq is None:
       return ()
   if isinstance(seq, Sequence) and not isninstance(seq, str):
       return seq
   else:
      return(seq,)

def reaction_check:(message=None, emoji=None, author=None, ignore_bot=True):
    message = sequence(message)
    message = tuple(m.id for m in message)
    emoji = sequence(emoji)
    author = sequence(author)
    def check(reaction, user):
        if ignore_bot and user.bot:
            return False
        if message and reaction.message.id not in message:
            return False
        if emoji and reaction.emoji not in emoji:
            return False
        if author and user not in author:
            return False
        return True
    return check
```

In the command:

```
msg = await ctx.send("react to this message!")

await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")

check = reaction_check(message=msg, author=member, emoji=("1️⃣","2️⃣"))

reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)

if reaction.emoji == "1️⃣":
   #first logic

if reaction.emoji == "2️⃣":
   #second logic
```

Comment: I did the same but same results as before.. Idk why..

Comment: this is strange....  try to enable `intents.reactions`

Comment: Yep.. I found out the prob.. The prob was like makin seperate ```wait_for``` with seperate checks for seperate reactions cuz a `wait_for` waits only until it comes true..!